# Second use of `gls` prints whole acronym-definition again when using inside tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, glossaries

I encountered a problem with `glossaries` and `tikz`. When using `\gls` inside a `tikzpicture` the second use of `\gls` prints the whole thing again, not only the acronym. Is there some kind of problem I don't get?
See the MWE'ish code below.

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    aspectratio=1610,
    x11names,
    ]{beamer}

\definecolor{AADarkBlue}{RGB}{33,26,82}
\definecolor{AAGreyBlue}{RGB}{84,97,110}

\usepackage[automake,acronym,nopostdot,shortcuts=all,nonumberlist,xindy]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\scriptsize}
\makeglossaries
\AtBeginDocument{\glsaddall}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {rectangle, draw=AAGreyBlue, fill=AADarkBlue!30, text width=3.5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em},
    line/.style = {draw=AAGreyBlue, color=AAGreyBlue, -latex'},
    }

\newglossaryentry{PTCA}{
    type=\acronymtype,
    name={PTCA},
    description={perkutane transluminale koronare Angioplastie},
    first={perkutane transluminale koronare Angioplastie (PTCA)}
}

\begin{filecontents}{FlowTherapyOptionsPTCA.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = .75cm,
    auto,
    font=\footnotesize,
    ]
    \tikzset{
        every node/.style={
            text=AAGreyBlue
        }
    }
    % Place nodes
    \node [block, text width=8.25em] (PTCA) {\glsfirst{PTCA} notwendig};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{FlowDosingScheme.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = .75cm,
    auto,
    font=\footnotesize,
    ]
    \tikzset{
        every node/.style={
            text=AAGreyBlue
        },
    }
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (Cangrelor) {KengrexalVial};
    \node [block, below left=of Cangrelor, text width=5cm, minimum height=1.5cm] (PTCA) {
        stuff};
    \node [block, below right=of Cangrelor, text width=5cm, minimum height=1.5cm] (Bridging) {
        mor stuff};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (Cangrelor.265) |- ([xshift=-.25cm,yshift=-.25cm]Cangrelor.260)  -| node [near start, above, font=\scriptsize] {\gls{PTCA}} (PTCA.north);
    \path [line] (Cangrelor.275) |- ([xshift=.25cm,yshift=-.25cm]Cangrelor.270)  -| node [near start, above, font=\scriptsize] {Bridging} (Bridging.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \input{FlowTherapyOptionsPTCA}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \input{FlowDosingScheme}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\glsfirst is one of the \glstext-like commands mentioned in section 6.2 of glossaries-user.pdf. These commands "don’t change or reference the
first use flag" -- thus, when you use \gls{PTCA} in the picture, it is regarded as first-time use.

I guess you just misinterpreted the command name: As I understand it, \glsfirst is not to be used the *first time you reference a glossary entry*, but *if you want a reference to look just like it was used the first time*. That makes perfectly sense -- if you had to use \glsfirst the first time you use a glossary entry and \gls only after that, you would have to keep track of which glossary entries you have already used all by yourself. That would make using the glossaries-package almost pointless, as it takes all the magic away.

Short answer: Use \gls instead of \glsfirst, and you should be set!

Comment: Ohh, that's embarrassing. I coded the first picture a couple of days ago und the second today. I forgot that I used `\glsfirst` in the first picture. Totally my fault; I know the difference between `\gls` and `\glsfirst`.